# SQL query count customers

Tags: mysql, sql

I need count how many suppliers have status "*CLOSED*" or "*READY FOR AUDIT*", but in the same time I don't want to count those suppliers that have status "NULL".

| supplier | status |
| --- | --- |
| JUSTRITE MANUFACTURING COMPANY | CLOSED |
| JW SPEAKER CORPORATION | CLOSED |
| KLEIN TOOLS INC | NULL |
| KLEIN TOOLS INC | CLOSED |
| KLEVER INNOVATIONS | CLOSED |
| LA-CO INDUSTRIES INC | CLOSED |

As we can see in this example, there are 5 different customers, but the results will be "4" because `KLEINT` contains "NULL" and it shouldn't be counted in.

Comment: What if a supplier have both statuses `CLOSED` and `READY FOR AUDIT` ?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say table is defined like the following:

```
Table name: your_table with two fields

supplier          status    
----------------  ------
```

Then you can get the result by aggregation function `count`.

```
SELECT 
   supplier,
   SUM(IFNULL((SELECT 1 FROM your_table WHERE a. supplier = supplier LIMIT 1), 0)) AS cnt
FROM your_table a
WHERE `status` IN ('CLOSED', 'READY')
GROUP BY supplier
HAVING cnt > 0
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a fiddle for you with the solution as an example

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rW914i1yUA5GBK2d9j6PGB/0

also the code should look like this

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM test
WHERE STATUS IS NOT NULL
    AND STATUS IN (
        'CLOSED'
        ,'READY FOR AUDIT'
        )
```

this code ignores  NULL values, (but they have to be empty values, not someone typing NULL in the fields. that makes a diffrence)

Comment: This won't work with the example provided in the question statement: `KLEIN TOOLS` will be counted in even though it should be counted out.

Comment: i might be understanding it wrong. they said they dont want the null KLEIN TOOLS
If they want the KLEIN TOOLS then simply remove -- where status is not null and --

Comment: ohh wait I get you..  ill fix it soon

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- select all suppliers which have "*CLOSED*" or "*READY FOR AUDIT*" status
- remove from the selection all those that have a "*NULL*" status

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT supplier) 
FROM tab 
WHERE status IN ('CLOSED', 'READY FOR AUDIT')
  AND supplier NOT IN (SELECT supplier FROM tab WHERE status IS NULL)
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c2dd8f7672ecca3a81d6587588d44226).

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH CTE(COMPANY,STATUSS) AS
(
   SELECT  'JUSTRITE MANUFACTURING COMPANY',  'CLOSED' UNION ALL
   SELECT'JW SPEAKER CORPORATION',          'CLOSED' UNION ALL
   SELECT'KLEIN TOOLS INC' ,                NULL UNION ALL
   SELECT'KLEIN TOOLS INC' ,                'CLOSED' UNION ALL
   SELECT'KLEVER INNOVATIONS',              'CLOSED' UNION ALL
   SELECT'LA-CO INDUSTRIES INC'  ,          'CLOSED'
)
SELECT COUNT(C.COMPANY)
FROM CTE AS C
WHERE C.STATUSS IN('CLOSED','READY FOR AUDIT')
AND NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM CTE AS X WHERE C.COMPANY=X.COMPANY AND X.STATUSS IS NULL
)
```

CTE is an example of your data. Please replace it with your table name

Comment: why do you need a CTE for this ?

Comment: example of data provided by topic-starter

Comment: I am sorry, still confused.  how does the data suggest that we need a recursion for such a simple query ?

Comment: Sorry, it is not so simple. in the sample data the client 'KLEIN TOOLS INC ' is listed twice: as 'CLOSED' and with NULL-status. As per requirement, this client should be excluded